# WPF, EF: Show and save ordering of rows in datagrid, mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

My users want to be able to re-arrange the rows in some datagrids and other list controls. There is already an existing database with a SortOrder column (integer). I use entity framework 6.1. My view needs to show the items ordered by this column, and any changes to the ordering must be saved to the database as well, when the user clicks "save" and context.SaveChanges is called

My best attempt so far is to add a SortOrder column to my datagrid and sort by it (and I intend to make it invisible somehow...), attach PreviewKeyDown events for up/down that call commands in my viewmodel, that in turn update the SortOrder values. However, even if I do RaisePropertyChanged("MyDataGridItemSource"), the datagrid is not updated, and I've tried setting mode=twoway, NotifyBySource=true, NotifyByTarget=true. Re-setting the MyDataGridItemSource completely will update the value of the SortOrder column, but it will not re-arrange the rows according to it and I'll also lose my selection which is unwanted.

Do you have any good suggestions for mapping a database sorting column to controllers like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to wrap the collection in a `CollectionViewSource`.

First of all you need to make sure that collection items implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `PropertyChanged` event is raised whenever the `SortOrder` property changes. Then define collection view source like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionView" Source="{Binding Collection}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SortOrder" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

where `xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"`, and put it in a `DataGrid`'s ancestor control's resources dictionary (for example in `Window.Resources` or `UserControl.Resources`). Lastly set the defined collection view source as items source of your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionView}}">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Now whenever `SortOrder` property is changed on any item the UI should be updated accordingly.

**UPDATE**

If items do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` the above solution won't work. You may want to consider creating a wrapper class that would expose necessary properties and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (this design pattern is commonly known as "decorator pattern"). However, if it is not an option, you can define collection view on your view model and bind to it instead to the collection itself, and manually refresh the view whenever any changes are made to items. Here's an example of how it might look like:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> Collection 
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {
        //store the value in the backing field
        if (value != null)
        {
            CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value);
            CollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription
            {
                Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending,
                PropertyName = "SortOrder",
            });
        }
        else
            CollectionView = null;
    }
}

public ICollectionView CollectionView
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {
        //store the value in the backing field and raise PropertyChanged
    }
}
```

In XAML, bind to the collection view:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Then, whenever you make changes to items, call `CollectionView.Refresh()` when you're done and UI will be updated.

Comment: The collection I'm binding to is a property that is returning the entity framework entities in question, so the items do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, however, I can raise events whenever I'm making changes to SortOrder, will that work as well?

Comment: I changed how entity framework generates classes so that they now implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then got your first solution working, thanks!